# Help finding the values for $a$ and $b$ that make the function continuous and differentiable everywhere.

Tags: calculus

> Finding the values for $a$ and $b$ that make the function continuous and differentiable everywhere.
>   $$L(t) = \begin{cases}
> \dfrac at & t \le 1 \\
> 3t+b & t > 1
> \end{cases}$$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the definition of continuity and differentiability and what informations do they give for the function at $t = 1$?

Comment: I figured out that a = 3 + b. Continuity means there are no holes or gaps in the graphs (the pencil test), and differentiability means you can take the derivative of the function. At t = 1 the need to meet and form a continuous, differentiable graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HINTS

Continuity: $\dfrac a{(1)} = 3(1)+b$

Differentiability: $\dfrac{-a}{(1)^2} = 3$

Comment: I found the derivative from the left side and the derivative from the right side.

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Simply do$$ \lim _{x \rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=lim _{x \rightarrow 1^+}f(x)$$

To get $a=3+b$.

Now for differentiation, $$ \lim _{x \rightarrow 1^-}f^{'}(x)=lim _{x \rightarrow 1^+}f{'}(x)$$
To get $a=-3$

Please note that my diffrentiation test is not the best thing any one would approve of but to get actual diffrentaition test across a point, Please do$$LHD=RHD \rightarrow \lim _ {h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{-h}=\lim _ {h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

AND PLEASE TELL US WHAT YOU ATTEMPTED YET.TO MAKE SURE THAT I IMPROVE MY ANSWER